# How to expose class array parameter to COM using Interopservices?

Tags: c#, arrays, vb6, com-interop

I have been searching for several days and still have not found the correct answer.  I did find [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/107d4454-b079-434b-a7f4-470a0ca41c6a/how-to-expose-class-array-parameter-to-com-using-interopservices) similar question which maybe moving in the correct direction.I'm working in C# using VS2008 and need to communicate with a VB6 application.  My problem is that I have a number of configuration type classes that I need to expose via COM, so that the data contained can be accessed by the VB6 application. I was doing very well with this until one of my classes needed to expose a class array parameter. My C# code is something like this:

```
    [Guid("..."),InterfaceType(ComInterface.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface iClientComInterop
    {
       [DispID(1) Properties GetData();
    }


    [Guid("..."), ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None),ProgIdAttribute("ClientComInterop"),ComDefaultInterfaceAttribute(typeof(iClientComInterop))]
    public class ClientComInterop : iClientComInterop
    {
        public ClientComInterop()
        {
        }
        public Properties GetData()
        {...}

     }
     [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
     [Guid("...")]
     public interface iProperties
     {
         [DispId(1)]
         int Id{get; }
         [DispId(2)]
         ProcessingInformation ProcessingInfo { get;  }
     }

      [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
      [ProgId("ConfigurationTypes.Properties")]
      [Guid("...")]
      public class Properties : iProperties
      {
        public int Id
        {
          get ;
          set ;
        }
        public ProcessingInformation ProcessingInfo
        {
          get ;
          set ;
        }

    public Properties()
    {
      ...
    }
  }
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
  [Guid("...")]
  public interface iProcessingInformation
  {
    [DispId(1)]
    bool Enabled {get; }
    [DispId(2)]
    AccountInformation[] accounts  {  [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]get; }

  }
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  [ProgId("ConfigurationTypes.ProcessingInformation")]
  [Guid("...")]
  public class ProcessingInformation : iProcessingInformation
  {
    public bool Enabled
    {
      get ; 
      set ; 
    }
    public AccountInformation[] Accounts
    {
      get;
      set;
    }     
    public ProcessingInformation()
    {
      ...
    }
  }
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
  [Guid("...")]
  public interface iAccountInformation
  {
     [DispId(1)]
     int Type {get; }
     [DispId(2)]
     double balance{ get;  }
  }
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  [ProgId("ConfigurationTypes.AccountInformation")]
  [Guid("...")]
   public class AccountInformation: iAccountInformation
  {
    public int Type
    {
      get ;
      set ;
    }
    public double balance
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public AccountInformation()
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

This all compiles, registers and shows up in the VB6 Object Browser looking correct, but I have not been able to retrieve the array of AccountInformation from ProcessingInformation. I'm getting  Object Mismatch error. This data needs to be retrieved as part of the object Properties using the GetData() function.  I'm at a complete loss as to how I should go about this. I can pull any of the other information from Properties and ProcessingInformation but not the information in the AccountInformation array.

VB6 Example:

```
Public Client As ClientComInterop.ClientComInteropSet
Client = CreateObject("ClientComInterop")
Dim data as ConfigurationTypes.PropertiesSet
data = Client.GetData()
Print "ID: " ; data.ID    ' This works
Print "Process enabled: "; data.ProcessingInfo.Enabled   ' This works
Print "Accounts Type: "; data.ProcessingInfo.Accounts(0).Type  ' error Type mismatch
```

I have trying several other things as well, such as creating a local array of Accounts and attempted to set this with data.ProcessingInfo.Accounts. This didn't work either, I get the same error "Type mismatch".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this signature for `accounts` property:

```
AccountInformation[] accounts  
{  
    [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, 
        SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] get; 
}
```

**[UPDATE]** I don't have VB6, but here's what works for me with VBScript. I must admit, within the reasonable amount of time I spent on this, I couldn't find a better way of doing it, including how to directly access an element by index (i.e. `processInfo.Accounts(0)`):

**VBScript:**

```vbs
' this works:
For Each a in processInfo.Accounts 
  MsgBox a.balance
Next 

' this doesn't:
MsgBox processInfo.Accounts(0)
```

**C#:**

```cs
public interface iProcessingInformation
{
    [DispId(2)]
    object[] Accounts
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ProcessingInformation : iProcessingInformation
{
    public object[] Accounts
    {
        get
        {
            return new object[] { new AccountInformation() };
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't fix the issue. I'm now not getting the 'error Type mismatch, but I can not see the array or even identify Accounts as an array in the VB6 code, with the above print statement. The runtime error is now, "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".  If I create an array of type Variant in my VB6 code, and attempt to set this with data from data.ProcessingInfo.Accounts, I'm still getting the type mismatch error.

Comment: @Norseratio,Thank you for your continued efforts. Sorry I have been so long in getting back to this.  Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the solution in this case. The only way I have found, that will allow me to access any of actual data in the array is to change the class interface on ProcessingInformation from None to AutoDual. This is not the best case for me, it allow access to other item in ProcessingInformation that are not part of the interface.